# How do I use Sequelize to express a conditional COUNT aggregator on the presence of a nested jsonb field?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Here is the raw query I'm trying to convert to Sequelize, where `response` is a JSONB column of the `posts` table, and may or may not have an `error` attribute.

```
SELECT post_id, 
  COUNT(response -> 'error' IS NOT NULL) as "response_errors"
FROM posts
WHERE post_id in (<list of post ids>)
GROUP BY post_id
```

I expect this query to return an array where each entry has a `post_id`, and `response_errors` attribute counting the number of rows in `posts` for each `post_id` with a `response` containing an `error`.

Where I'm having trouble in my `findAll` options definition is the `attributes` array. I'm not sure how to implement the aggregation on the nested value of a jsonb column.

```
    {
      where: {
        postId: postIds,
      },
      attributes: [
        'postId',
        [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', { response: { error: { $ne: null } } }), 'responseErrors'],
      ],
      group: ['postId'],
      order: [Sequelize.col('post_id')],
      raw: true,
    }
```

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks!